# Blazor WASM Only Runs on Rebuild

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I just started having this issue where if I make a small change to any project within my Blazor WASM project the application refuses to launch correctly unless I rebuild the entire solution. This is obviously really inconvenient. Has this happened to anyone else? I am at a loss as to what is causing it, so not quite sure what other information to add. It is a self hosted model, all projects are using .NET7 this is my Server project set up:

```xml
 <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

This is my WASM project settings

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

 -----project deps-----
</Project>
```

For further reference I sometimes get these errors where these files don't load correctly:

```
[15:22:38 INF] HTTP GET /_framework/debug/ws-proxy responded 302 in 643.6186 ms
[15:22:39 INF] HTTP GET /Butterfly.styles.css responded 404 in 147.1415 ms
[15:22:39 INF] HTTP GET /_framework/blazor.webassembly.js responded 404 in 150.7500 ms
```

I've tried on Chrome, Firefox and Edge and these errors remain until I rebuild the entire solution. I've also tried disabling AOT compilation with no effect that I can see.

If I try to rebuild only the project with changes in it, I get random errors like:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Query, Version=1.0.0.0,`

or errors like `Could not resolve the signature of a virtual method System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve the signature of a virtual method` on an overloaded method that is definitely correct.

Comment: Yes, I started experiencing this same problem around the beginning of 2023. I now need to manually build the project each time I launch it to get changes to replicate over to the browser and often I need to manually refresh or close and reopen the browser to see the latest changes.